# agrepl does not work with regular expressions

Tags: regex, r

I need to get partial matching in a string using regexs. I can get exact ones:

```
pattern <- "(^| )shower only($| )"

stringInQuestion<-"Delta Vero 1-Handle Shower Only Faucet Trim Kit in Chrome"

grepl(pattern,stringInQuestion, ignore.case=TRUE,perl=TRUE)

[1] TRUE

agrepl(pattern,stringInQuestion, ignore.case=TRUE,fixed = FALSE, max.distance=0.2)

[1] FALSE
```

Works only for plain character strings:

```
agrepl("shower only",stringInQuestion, ignore.case=TRUE,fixed = FALSE, max.distance=0.2)
```

Can somebody please help me to figure out what is going on?

Comment: Study the `max.distance` argument. If you set it to e.g. 10, it works.

Comment: Change the pattern to [`pattern <- "\\bshower only\\b"`](http://ideone.com/PLUH4K). You need to only check the whole word `shower only`, so use word boundaries. `0.2` will allow matching the phrase with errors, say `Showerrrrr Only`, but won't match `Showerrrrrr Only`

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you intend to just check for a whole word presence, I suggest reducing the pattern to

```
pattern <- "\\bshower only\\b"
```

See the official description of the `max.distance` argument:

> `max.distance`
>   Maximum distance allowed for a match. Expressed either as integer, or as a ***fraction*** of the pattern length times the maximal transformation `cost` (will be replaced by the smallest integer not less than the corresponding fraction), or a list with possible components

`0.2` will allow matching the phrase with errors, say `Showerrrrr Only`, but won't match `Showerrrrrr Only`. See this [working demo](http://ideone.com/PLUH4K):

```
pattern <- "\\bshower only\\b"
stringInQuestion<-"Delta Vero 1-Handle Shower Only Faucet Trim Kit in Chrome"
grepl(pattern,stringInQuestion, ignore.case=TRUE,perl=TRUE)
agrepl(pattern,stringInQuestion, ignore.case=TRUE,fixed = FALSE, max.distance=0.2)
## [1] TRUE
## [1] TRUE
```

Note that the `max.distance` should be tested against the real input you have and asjust accordingly.

Comment: I second this. I've tried to make this thing work:

```
> grepl("(\\s+)?", "abc ABC   123\t.!?\\(){}[]")
[1] TRUE
> agrepl("(\\s+)?", "abc ABC   123\t.!?\\(){}[]")
[1] FALSE
> agrepl("(\\s+)?", "abc ABC   123\t.!?\\(){}[]", max.distance = 1)
[1] FALSE
```

It should be `TRUE` in last 2 cases. It works only when I add `fixed = FALSE`, but it should be by default. Editing here does not allow me to go to a new line or add a blank line, even when I tried "copy and paste".

Comment: I guess my question now is "How I contact developers about it". Or can I fix it myself?